# Codeigniter function skipping

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi this is a simple question, however I have now stared at it long enough to realise im simply not seeing the error. If anyone can see where this is going wrong I would be very thankful.

```
public function create()
{
$this->load->model('ticket_model');

if($_POST)
    {
    // validate form
    if($this->_validate())
        {
        // save updates                                 
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){if(!is_array($value)) $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value);}

        if ($_POST['subject'] == '')    $body_data['error'][] = "You did not enter a subject.";
        if ($_POST['priority'] == '')   $body_data['error'][] = "You did not select a priority.";
        if ($_POST['status'] == '')     $body_data['error'][] = "You did not select a status.";
        if ($_POST['ipAddress'] == '')  $body_data['error'][] = "You did not enter a ipAddress.";
        if ($_POST['text_area'] == '') $body_data['error'][] = "You did not enter a message.";
        else
            {
            if (filter_var($_POST['ipAddress'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,  FILTER_FLAG_IPV4) == FALSE) $body_data['error'][] = "IP Address is not valid IPV4 Address.";
            if (filter_var($_POST['ipAddress'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,  FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE) == FALSE) $body_data['error'][] = "IP Address cannot be from RFC1918 private space.";
            if (filter_var($_POST['ipAddress'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,  FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) == FALSE) $body_data['error'][] = "IP Address cannot be from reserved range.";
            }
        if ($_FILES['filename']['name'] != '')
            {
            if ($_FILES['filename']['size'] > '1024000')
                {
                $body_data['error'][]                       = "The file you uploaded is too large.";

                unlink($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);

                $body_data['ticket_list']       = $this->ticket_model->list_ticket();
                $body_data['ticket_details']    = $this->ticket_model->get_ticket($ticket_id);
                $body_data['ticket_summary']    = $this->ticket_model->list_ticket_summary($ticket_id);

                $body_data['precan_list']       = $this->ticket_model->list_messages();
                $body_data['users_list']        = $this->ticket_model->list_users();
                $foot_data['accordian_active'] = 5;

                $this->load->view('head',$head_data);
                $this->load->view('sidebar/service',$head_data);
                $this->load->view('ticket/edit',$body_data);
                $this->load->view('foot',$foot_data);
                return;
                }
            else
                {
                //the file is under the specified size. so copy it from temp to import folder and proccess
                $thisFileHumanName      = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
                $thisFileSize           = $_FILES['filename']['size'];
                $thisServerFileName     = strtoupper(uniqid('A'));
                $thisFileType           = $_FILES['filename']['type'];

                $temp_file_location = $this->config->item('rootpath').'/assets/ticketuploads/'.$thisServerFileName;

                if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $temp_file_location))
                    {
                    $body_data['error'][]                       = "File could not be moved due to a permissions error.";

                    unlink($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);

                    $body_data['ticket_list']       = $this->ticket_model->list_ticket();
                    $body_data['ticket_details']    = $this->ticket_model->get_ticket($ticket_id);
                    $body_data['ticket_summary']    = $this->ticket_model->list_ticket_summary($ticket_id);

                    $body_data['precan_list']       = $this->ticket_model->list_messages();
                    $body_data['users_list']        = $this->ticket_model->list_users();
                    $foot_data['accordian_active'] = 5;

                    $this->load->view('head',$head_data);
                    $this->load->view('sidebar/service',$head_data);
                    $this->load->view('ticket/edit',$body_data);
                    $this->load->view('foot',$foot_data);
                    return;
                    }
                }
            }

        //clean error array
        $body_data['error']                     = array_filter($body_data['error']);

        if ($body_data['error'])
            {
            $body_data['ticket_list']       = $this->ticket_model->list_ticket();
            $body_data['ticket_details']    = $this->ticket_model->get_ticket($ticket_id);
            $body_data['ticket_summary']    = $this->ticket_model->list_ticket_summary($ticket_id);

            $body_data['precan_list']       = $this->ticket_model->list_messages();
            $body_data['users_list']        = $this->ticket_model->list_users();

            unlink($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);

            $foot_data['accordian_active'] = 5;

            $this->load->view('head',$head_data);
            $this->load->view('sidebar/service',$head_data);
            $this->load->view('ticket/edit',$body_data);
            $this->load->view('foot',$foot_data);
            return;
            }
        else
            {   

            $_POST['userId'] = $this->session->get_user_id();

            $thisMessageId = $this->ticket_model->save_message($_POST);

            if ($_FILES['filename']['name'] != '')
                {
                //set variables for save
                $_POST['file_path'] = $temp_file_location;
                $_POST['file_name'] = $thisFileHumanName;

                $_POST['file_size'] = $thisFileSize;
                $_POST['file_type'] = $thisFileType;
                $_POST['messageId'] = $thisMessageId;

                $this->ticket_model->save_upload($_POST);
                }
            $this->ticket_model->save_ticket($_POST);

            redirect(base_url().'ticket/');
            return;
            }
        }
    }
$body_data['ticket_list']        = $this->ticket_model->list_ticket();
$body_data['message_list']       = $this->ticket_model->list_message($ticket_id);
$body_data['customer_list']      = $this->ticket_model->list_customers();
$body_data['users_list']         = $this->ticket_model->list_users();

$foot_data['accordian_active'] = 5;
$foot_data['contact_search']   = true;
$this->load->view('head',$head_data);
$this->load->view('sidebar/service',$head_data);
$this->load->view('ticket/create',$body_data);
$this->load->view('foot',$foot_data);
return;
}
```

This is my code, and everything is going well, except for the section where i save the upload, as nothing seems to be firing the model, even thought there is a file being posted from the from submit and there for the filename being posted is `!= ''`......
e.g

```
if ($_FILES['filename']['name'] != '')
{
    //set variables for save
    $_POST['file_path'] = $temp_file_location;
    $_POST['file_name'] = $thisFileHumanName;

    $_POST['file_size'] = $thisFileSize;
    $_POST['file_type'] = $thisFileType;
    $_POST['messageId'] = $thisMessageId;

    $this->ticket_model->save_upload($_POST);
}
```

my apologies if this is silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing it this way? Codeigniter has a built in [class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) for uploading files. You also should be using the [input class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) instead of `$_POST`.
It will make it a lot easier!

As for your code. You're actually setting the $_POST variable and trying to use that in `save_ticket`. You can't do that.

> The predefined $_POST variable is used to collect values from a form
>   sent with method="post"

You're trying to use it the other way around.

So to make it work, change the $_POST into $something and it should work, but it's still not the way to go.

```
//set variables for save
$something['file_path'] = $temp_file_location;
$something['file_name'] = $thisFileHumanName;

$something['file_size'] = $thisFileSize;
$something['file_type'] = $thisFileType;
$something['messageId'] = $thisMessageId;

$this->ticket_model->save_upload($something);
```

Comment: the whole project has been adapted to Codeigniter rather than being built from ground up in Codeignitor. Is too much to change now really.

Comment: It might seem like a lot of work, but I bet that it will save you time. Instead of debugging, you can rewrite it, using much less code and it will work a lot better.

Comment: O i see what you mean, however I want to reassign these values to the post to like to a model linking it with SQL sepearately. I have tried your suggestion, I feel it is something more basic than that, more like an ordering of functions error. as it posts the "if ($_FILES['filename']['name'] != '')..... function when i remove the if statement, only with no values reaching the db. the exact problem occurs even when i change the post variable to $somethingelse.

Comment: I don't get that part about reassigning...? How about you place a simple print_r($_POST); on top to see what the variable contains.

Answer (score 0):

didn't have this set.......`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

red face on this end.